# Spark 1.6 load specific partition in dataframe keeping partition field

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-avro

We have an avro with partitioned like this:

```
table
--a=01
--a=02
```

We want to load the data from a single partition keeping the partition column a. 
I found [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34659184/how-to-load-specific-hive-partition-in-dataframe-spark-1-6) and I applied the suggested snippet:

```
DataFrame df = hiveContext.read().format(format).
option("basePath", "path/to/table/").
load("path/to/table/a=01")
```

but when I try to read the field *a* it says:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'a' given input columns: [b, c, d]
```

Is it possible in Spark Java API 1.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, the answer is... no, it's not possible.